# Godot 3.3.2 - Changing child variables from the parent without them being reset

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'm new to godot and I was trying to make a asteriods type game. But i'm having trouble getting my space ship to shoot.
The issue is that I can't get the bullet to fire in direction of the ship. I set an 'angle' variable in the ship and assign it to the bullet once it has been instanced, but i'm not sure how to use it in the bullet. The bullet will just move right no matter the angle of the ship.

Ship Firing Code:

```
func _process(_delta):
if Input.is_action_just_pressed("action_fire"):
    var Bullet_Instance = Bullet.instance()
    Bullet_Instance.angle = angle
    owner.add_child(Bullet_Instance)
```

Bullet Code:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

var angle = 0

var direction = Vector2(cos(angle), sin(angle))

func _physics_process(_delta):
    move_and_slide(direction*500)
```

I'm pretty sure that the angle variable is being reset to 0 in the bullet code after it has been set in the ship code, but i'm not sure how to fix this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `angle` variable is not being reset. The `direction` variable is not being updated when you set `angle`.

When the scene is instanced, here:

```
var Bullet_Instance = Bullet.instance()
```

These variables get their value:

```
var angle = 0

var direction = Vector2(cos(angle), sin(angle))
```

Then you set `angle`, here:

```
Bullet_Instance.angle = angle
```

But you don't use `angle` anymore, instead, you use `direction`:

```
func _physics_process(_delta):
    move_and_slide(direction*500)
```

---

I'll give a few ways to solve this:

- If you want `direction` to update every time you set `angle`, you could make a setter with `setget`. Like this:

  ```
  var angle = 0 setget set_angle

  func set_angle(new_value) -> void:
      angle = new_value
      direction = Vector2(cos(angle), sin(angle))
  ```
- You could write `direction` directly from your other script, and not have the `angle` variable at all. *In fact, you could set a `velocity`, and save tha multiplication by `500` every time.*
- You could compute the vector on `_physics_process` (you are already doing a vector scaling operation anyway):

  ```
  func _physics_process(_delta):
      move_and_slide(Vector2(cos(angle)*500, sin(angle)*500))
  ```

There likely are more ways to go about it. It is up to you.